# Compare two dates strictly in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to compare two dates where the first is always greater than the second, it is important to note that the format obtained comes in `yyyyMM/dd`.

For example:

```
var date1 = yyyy/MM/dd;
var date2 = yyyy/MM/dd;
date1> date2
```

the possible solutions like data1.getTime (), have not worked for me.

I am using AngularJS 1.5.11

I ask you please help me

Comment: the "possible solution" should be `(new Date(date1)).getTime()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
                    var first = "2017/11/16";
                    var second = "2017/11/14"
                    var valuate1 = (new Date(first)).getTime();
                    var valuate2 = (new Date(second)).getTime();


                    if(valuate1 > valuate2)
                    {
                     console.log(true);
                    }else{
                      console.log(false);
                    }
```

Thank you very much @Aleksey Solovey for your clarification!